# REST how to make POST request

Tags: java, xml, rest

I m trying to post xml from client and consume xml from my service. When i try the following code i m getting unsupported media type exception. 
I tried to follow this example: 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/xml-example-with-jersey-jaxb/
What am i doing wrong ? Any ideas ?

Client side :

```
  private void request(String url,Event event) throws IOException, SAXException {
            try {

                Client client = Client.create();
                ClientResponse response = null;
                WebResource webResource = client
                        .resource(url);
                    if(event != null){

                     response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                                .post(ClientResponse.class,event);

                }else{
                 response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                        .get(ClientResponse.class);
                }
                if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + response.getStatus());
                }

                String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                System.out.println(output);

            }catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Server side :

```
@POST
    @Path("/created")
    @Consumes({"application/xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,"text/html"})
    @Produces ({"application/xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,"text/html"})
    public Response createEvent( @FormParam("eventtitle") String title,
            @FormParam("eventtype") String type,
            @FormParam("eventdescription") String description,
            @FormParam("eventlocation") String location,
            @FormParam("eventdate") String date,
            @FormParam("eventcreationdate") String creationdate,
            @FormParam("eventmodificationdate") String modificationdate,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "<h4>Event sucessfully created </h4>");
        sb.append("<br></br><li><p><a href=\"/\">go back</a></p></li>");
        Response.status(200).entity(sb.toString()).build();
        Event event = eventWorker.createEvent(title,type,description,location,date,
                creationdate,modificationdate);
        return Response.ok(sb.toString()).cacheControl(CC).build();
    }
```

Comment: Akin, my first guess would be Content-Type - I don't see where you set it. Second might be server itself - supposed to have Access-Control-Allow-Methods allowing POST. These are where I was missing when I was dealing with my API. It might help.